# JOIN exclude records in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my system one order can have associated X documents, and each documents have an document code.

One example of my schema with data:

| Order | Document | Code Doc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 5E |
| 1 | 102 | 5E |
| 1 | 103 | 1DE |
| 2 | 201 | 5E |

The table of the orders is `PDOCAS` and the documents save in the table `DOCCAB`.

I would like when join the orders with the documents, that if one of the types of documents is 1DE, do not bring the order.

```
select p.DocCabIdDeb as 'Order', d.DocCabId as 'Document', d.DocCod as 'Code Doc' 
from PDOCAS p 
JOIN DOCCAB d on p.DocCabIdHab=d.DocCabId
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select * from DOCCAB ds where ds.DocCabId=d.DocCabId and doccod='1DE')
and p.DocCabIdDeb in (1, 2)
```

In this case, it returns me the order 1 and the 5E document codes, and I don't want it to return it because one of the documents of order 1 is 1DE.

Should I join the tables in another way?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you can use `outer apply` here. Please show all relevant tables and data, your sample query refers to column names that are diffrent to your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made few assumptions on the data
You need an inner query or [CTE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cte-in-sql/)s which filter out the orders containing the blacklisted Doc codes

So you need a distinct order where document code in '1de'
and then you should filter out the orders from original table with an order_id not in condition.

Below is an example query with CTE

```
WITH
-- Setting up the data 
PDOCAS AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
        (1, 101),
        (1, 102),
        (1, 103),
        (2, 201)
    ) t(DocCabIdDeb, DocCabIdHab)
),

DOCCAB AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        (101, '5E'),
        (102, '5E'),
        (103, '1DE'),
        (201, '5E')
    ) t(DocCabId, DocCod)
),
-- Data setup ends

-- Your actual query starts from here
ORDERS AS (
    select 
        p.DocCabIdDeb as "OrderId",
        d.DocCabId as "Document", 
        d.DocCod as "CodeDoc" 
    from 
        PDOCAS p
        JOIN DOCCAB d on p.DocCabIdHab=d.DocCabId
    WHERE
        p.DocCabIdDeb in (1, 2)
),

ORDERS_WITH_BLACKLISTED_DOCCOD AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        o.OrderId 
    FROM 
        ORDERS o
    WHERE
        o.CodeDoc in ('1DE') 
),

FINAL_ORDERS AS (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        ORDERS o
    WHERE
        o.OrderId NOT IN (SELECT * FROM ORDERS_WITH_BLACKLISTED_DOCCOD)
)

SELECT * FROM FINAL_ORDERS
```